# Using 'in' keyword to check for 0 always returns true?

Tags: javascript

Take the following piece of code:

```
var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function check(num) {
    if (num !== undefined) {
        if (num in testArr) {
            alert("in");
        } else {
            alert("not in");
        }
    }
}
```

With the `check()` function I try to check whether a given parameter is part of the `testArr` array or not.

In general the function works fine, only when checking for `0` the condition is met, although `0` is not part of the array. See for yourself: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kufzf0w7/)

Why is this happening?

One possible solution I could think of is that `0` is evaluated as `false` in some cases (`==` vs `===`), but when passing `false` as argument, the condition is not met, which does not make any sense to me – I am puzzled.

Comment: `in` checks if the **key** `num`  exists in the `testArr` and not if there is **value** `num` in it. And as there is an element at the index `0`  the result is true. You are looking for `testArr.indexOf(num)` [MDN: Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `[].indexOf(elem)` ([doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)) and check for `-1` if it's not in the array.  There's also a few other ways mentioned in this question [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/1059070)

Your code would be updated as follows:

```
var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function check(num) {
    if (num !== undefined) {
        if (testArr.indexOf(num) != -1) {
            alert("in");
        } else {
            alert("not in");
        }
    }
}
```

The `in` operator searches for keys and `0` will be a valid index in any nonempty array.  `in` does not return true for all arrays.  Try it with an empty array `[]`

Answer (score 2):

In this case you returned that the index exists in the array but not the value. See this documentation [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). I think that you must validate values of array with indexOf function.

Answer (score 1):

"in" is checking by key.
You have testArr[0] so you can get alert("in").

That is, if u use check(0)~check(4) will be alert("in"), 
other will be alert("not in") such as check(5).

```js
var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function check(num) {
  if (num in testArr) {
    return "check(" + i + ") = in ";
  } else {
    return "check(" + i + ") = not in ";
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  document.write(check(i) + "<br>")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The prop parameter from the `in` operator will search a property or check if an index exists.

From the documentation:

> prop: A string or numeric expression representing a property name or
>   array index.

And from one of it's examples:

> You must specify the index number, not the value at that index.

If you do:

```
<script>

var trees = new Array("redwood", "bay", "cedar", "oak", "maple");

'length' in trees // returns true because length is a property.

</script>
```

So in your case you are asking the `check` function if index 0 exists.